# XCode : Xcode 4.5.2 (though having all the SDK of Xcode 4.6 -- both iphoneOS & Sim) not detecting iOS 6.1.3 device

Tags: xcode4.5

I have both **Xcode 4.5.2** & **Xcode 4.6** and also an iPod with **iOS 6.1.3**.

Now when I connect the device and use Xcode 4.6 - device is detected.
But the device is not detected with Xcode 4.5.2 .

Please note both versions of Xcode have exactly the same SDKs.

Any idea ???

Thanks!

Comment: how do you know they have exactly the same SDK's?  [Xcode 4.5.2 had a SDK for iOS 6.0 and Xcode 4.6 had the SDK for iOS 6.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#4.5.2).

Comment: @MichaelDautermann : I copied the SDKs present in XCode 4.6 (Show Package Contents-> Developer -> Platforms) to Xcode 4.5.2

Answer (score 0):

The above process *regarding copying the SDKs* work perfectly. I just restarted my machine.